# Sharing friends thoughts with my network PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql

TABLE's :

```
members (id, fname, lname,...)
my_connections(id, member_id, connection_id, approved, ...)
my_thoughts(id, member_id, thought, shared, ...)
```

I have a feed of my networks thoughts based on my_connections, How would I share my connections thoughts with my network.

I need to pass all the data related to that thought (including who it belongs to) so that it shows up in my networks feed as

```
John smith shared a thought from Jane smith
```

What I have tried:
I built a join table i.e

```
shared_thoughts (id, member_id, thought_id, belongs_to_id, ...)
```

but I think im going about it the wrong way.

QUESTION : How do I share my connections thoughts with my network?

Comment: is there a question actually?

Comment: edited with question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'share my connections thoughts with my network'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems right to me. Adding a relation between `member` and `thought` should be enough.

```
shared_thoughts (id, member_id, thought_id)
```

You've added `belongs_to_id`, but this seems unnecessary (not normalized). You can find that out through the `thought_id`.